# TypeError: cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer - django

Tags: python, django, post, request

I am trying to make a post request to mailchimp's api.  It works perfectly fine when I am doing it in my local machine but somehow when I push it into the cloud.  This error appears and I thought it was because of the python version since it's the only differences between local and the cloud.  In cloud it's python `2.7.6` local I am using `2.7.12`

I have searched up but a few issues only talks about other lib that's causing the error.  I didn't have new `requirements` installed at all.

I can calling a `post request` by using something like `requests.post(MAILCHAMP_API, payload, headers=headers).json()`

Then I get an error of
`cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface`
`Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in sendall, line 216`

Comment: Which version of `pyopenssl` are you using? Maybe https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/719 could be the culprit

Comment: @StuartDines where can I find the version of pyopenssl?